# Proving that $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|^{-1}\leqslant 4$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am asked to prove that $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|^{-1}\leqslant 4$ for all $\sigma\geqslant 2$ and $|t|\geqslant 1$. Of course, one can use the fact that
$$ \zeta(\sigma+it)^{-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{\sigma+it}} $$
and therefore $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|^{-1}\leqslant\zeta(\sigma)\leqslant\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. But this is not in the spirit of the question I am being asked as the Möbius function is not supposed to be known. Instead, I was first asked to show that $\zeta(\sigma)\leqslant 1+\frac{1}{2^{\sigma}}+\frac{1}{(\sigma-1)2^{\sigma-1}}$, which comes from an integral comparison. I don't know how to get the upper bound from this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how one gets the desired bound (which is a lower bound on $|\zeta(s)|$) from an upper bound on $\zeta(\sigma)$. Without being able to use the Möbius function, I would be inclined to try using the Euler product for $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Yes this is what I thought. I also tried to use the Euler product, I tried to get an upper bound of the form  $$ |1-p_n^{-\sigma-it}|\leqslant\frac{a_n}{1-p_n^{-\sigma}} $$ where $\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n\leqslant 4$ but couldn't find one.

Comment: Getting an upper bound for $\zeta(s)^{-1}$ using the Euler product just requires an inequality $|1-p^{-\sigma-it}| \le c_p$ for some constant $c$ depending on $p$, and then the upper bound obtained is $\prod_p c_p$. The best possible $c_p$ can be determined geometrically (what is the locus of $1-p^{-\sigma-it}$ as $t$ varies with $p$ and $\sigma$ fixed?).

Comment: Note that by the triangle inequality $|\zeta(\sigma+it)| \ge 2-\zeta(\sigma) \ge 1/4$ by the inequality you obtained since $ 1+\frac{1}{2^{\sigma}}+\frac{1}{(\sigma-1)2^{\sigma-1}} \le 1+1/4+1/2$

Comment: @GregMartin It is on the circle of radius $p^{-\sigma}$ and center $1$, therefore $|1-p^{-\sigma-it}|\leqslant 1+p^{-\sigma}=\frac{1-p^{-2\sigma}}{1-p^{-\sigma}}$. We thus get $$ |\zeta(\sigma+it)|^{-1}\leqslant\frac{\zeta(\sigma)}{\zeta(2\sigma)}\leqslant\zeta(\sigma)\leqslant 1 $$

Comment: @Conrad Oh I see, how do you get $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|\geqslant 2-\zeta(\sigma)$ though ?

Comment: $|\zeta(\sigma+it)| \ge 1-\sum_{n \ge 2}n^{-\sigma}=2-\zeta(\sigma)$

Comment: @Conrad Ok I get it, thanks both of you !

Comment: Apart from your "instructions", I do most like the method for your estimate $|\zeta(\sig+it)|^{-1}\le \zeta(\sig(/\zeta(2\sig)$. :)